# How to calculate minimum unixtimestamp value using sparksql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
completion time | unixtimestamp | user|
0.07            |1529094938000  |user3|  
0.16            |1529094944000  |user2|
0.27            |1529094947000  |user1|
0.08            |1529094950000  |user2|
0.24            |1529094953000  |user1|
0.10            |1529094956000  |user1|
0.64            |1529094959000  |user3|
0.13            |1529094962000  |user3|
0.67            |1529094965000  |user1|
```

I want minimum timestamp for every user. How can we do it using Sparksql?

Assume the above table is in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

we will first convert the timestamp field into integer type if it is not already by any chance.

```
val new_dataframe =  dataframe.select($"unixtimestamp".cast(IntegerType).as("unixtimestamp"))
```

1) Create sqlContext in spark if not exists using the SparkContext object

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

2) Register this dataframe as a table

```
new_dataframe.registerTempTable("user_timestamp_data")
```

3) Now with the prior created sqlContext we can query as

```
    val result = 
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT q.user,ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(q.min)*1000) as 
    MinimumUnixTimeStamp
    FROM (
    select  user, MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtimestamp/1000) min 
    FROM user_timestamp_data
    GROUP BY user
    ORDER BY user ASC) AS q ")
```

That should give you users and their corresponding minimum timestamp value

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy` and `agg`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("user").agg(min(col("unixtimestamp")))
```